# Speed up a for loop with matrix multiplication?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop

one of the part  of my programme contains this piece of code:

```
size2=2500;
gran=3; 

A=ones(size2,size2);

for k=1:gran:(size2-gran)
    for j=1:gran:(size2-gran)

       X=rand*2*pi-pi;

       for h=1:gran
            for l=1:gran

               A(k+l-1,j+h-1) = A(k+l-1,j+h-1) *exp(+1i*X);  %phase in the square gran x gran

            end
        end
    end
end
```

My pc runs this code in 0.60 seconds but I would like to know if it is possible to speed up this process.

A faster way would be to write this as a matrix multiplication but in order to write X I think I have to create a for loop.

Is there any way to improve the speed of this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your for loop needs to be replaced by a matrix of random phases that has a 2x2 repeat.  can create the random variable as a matrix of size `A`

```
X = rand(size2/2)*2*pi-pi;
X = kron(X,ones(2));
```

then

```
A = A.*X;
```

Comment: no, my programme doesn't do that. I have a matrix size2 x size2 in which every cell in the square gran x gran starting from the (1,1) corner has the same random phase

Comment: i mistook `gran` to be the size of `A`... edited the answer...  all you do is give a random phase to each element of A

Comment: no, look at my programme. I don't give a random phase for each element of the matrix but for each square of size gran x gran of the matrix

Comment: I see... there are several ways to handle that, I'll edit my answer...